# How to generate $O(u_1^6+u_4^4)$ series

Tags: computational-mathematics, fractals, fractional-iteration

In the paper [**FRACTIONAL ITERATION OF SERIES AND TRANSSERIES**](https://people.math.osu.edu/edgar.2/preprints/trans_frac/fractional.pdf) by G. A. EDGAR, the solution to $f^s(x)=x^2+c$ is given:

> $$(19)\;\;\; M^{[s]} = \exp\circ M_1^{[s]}\circ\log =
>  x^{2^s}\left(1+2^{-1+s}c\mu_1^2-\frac{c}2\mu_4^2\\ \qquad
> \quad +\left(2^{-2+s}(c-c^2)+2^{-3+2s}c^2\right)\mu_1^4
> +2^{-2+s}c^2\mu_1^2\mu_4^2 + O(\mu_1^6+\mu_4^4)\right).$$
> This is a series in $\,\mu_0,\mu_1,\mu_4,\,$ but I do not
> know if $\,\mu_0=1/\log x\,$ actually appears. As before,
> the relative size of the terms depends on the value of $s$.

I am an amateur in mathematics and am unsure how to compute this series $O(u_1^6+u_4^4)$ for use in a program. The paper describes the $O$ function but I don't know how to interpret it:

> $$M_2 = x + \log 2-\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{A^j}j =
> x + \log 2 + \frac{c}2\mu_2\mu_3^2-\frac{c^2}4\mu_2\mu_3^4
> -\frac{c^2}8\mu_2^2\mu_3^4 +O(\mu_2\mu_3^6).$$
> The $O$ terms represents $\,\mu_2\mu_3^6\,$ times a series
> in $\,\mu_2,\mu_3\,$ with nonnegative exponents.

The function $M^{[s]}(x)$ with the $O$ terms omitted with my code creates a range of fractals for different $s$ (pictured: $s = 1$, ([$s = 1/2$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGldb.png))), I hope with the $O$ terms it should form the Mandelbrot fractal for any $s$, is this true?[image]

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpU3Z.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Q5J.png)

**Edit:**
every function inside $M^{[s]}$ relies on Abel's equation and solution $V$, given by $V_{n+1}=V_n(M_2(x))-log2$ , and it's inverse $V^{[-1]}$. For this I am unsure how to solve.

Comment: Big O notation is used in many fields, I think the use here would come under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinitesimal_asymptotics

Comment: On page 25 Edgar specifically mentions "Which of the two terms in the $\,O\,$ is larger depends on the value of $\,s.$" and gives the difference when $\,s>0\,$ where the first term is used and $\,s<0\,$ where the second term is used.

Comment: Even so, since $u_4$ and $u_6$ both rely on $x$, for $x < 1$ the relative error is very large. Is it clear that I am asking for the computable sum for this sequence? I am new to math overflow.

Comment: For $s=1$, $M(x)$ reduces to $M(x)=x^2+c+O(x^{-4})$, which is the mandelbrot set (with error)